# Python callback with parameters

Tags: python, class, parameters, callback

Here find a snippet

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, callback, *args, **kwargs):
    self.args=args
    self.kwargs=kwargs
    self.cb=callback

def rtCb(self):
    self.cb(self.args, self.kwargs)
    
def myCallback(*args, **kwargs):
    print('args: ', args)
    print('*args ', *args)
    print()
    print('kwargs :', kwargs)
    print('**kwargs :', **kwargs) 

mc=myClass(myCallback, 'pink', model='4wheels')
mc.rtCb()
```

When executed, prints indicate only args included kwargs. kwargs prints are empty
How I would like to obtain prints/values separate. Where is my bug ?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Also, you need to do `self.cb(*self.args, **self.kwargs)` so that it splats out your args and kwargs into the arguments for the function.